# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add_roles' / 'send'

Tags: python, discord

I'm new to discord.py and I tried to send a private message with my bot when I react with the 'bro_emoji' to a specific message :

```
@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):

    emoji = payload.emoji.name
    canal = payload.channel_id
    message = payload.message_id
    roles = bot.get_guild(payload.guild_id).roles
    bro_role = get(roles, name="Bro")
    member = bot.get_guild(payload.guild_id).get_member(payload.user_id)

    if emoji == "bro_emoji" and canal == 920004461575954472 and message == 920004958923939901:
        print('Role acquired')
        await member.add_roles(bro_role) # Issue here
        await member.send("Bro role acquired") # Issue here
```

There are the errors :

*AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add_roles'*

*AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'*

**Thanks :D <3**

Comment: Your `member` value is `None` so the line where you try to set `member =` is somehow failing.

Comment: `.get_member(payload.user_id)` must be returning None, so member is None.

Comment: So how should i do @JohnGordon to mp a member with his id/name ?

Comment: Like in all similar question, you should ask "Why do I have `None` here?". Typically, it's a bug or lack of error handling. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Ok thanks, so why do I have 'None' here ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I get AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'something'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949252/why-do-i-get-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-something)

Answer (score 0):

Try creating the variables that start by `bot.get_` in the `on_ready()` function and just making it global:

`global member`

`member = bot.get_guild(payload.guild_id).get_member(payload.user_id)`

Because if the bot isn't officially logged in the `bot.get_` functions return `None`. And the `on_ready()` function gets activated only when the bot is officially logged in.

Answer (score 0):

To piggyback off of Nickname's answer as it took me a moment to figure out what they meant, you need to put the "global member" in your on_ready method. Make sure your on_ready is inside the same file where you initialize the "bot" instance

```
bot = commands.Bot("<insert prefix here>", intents=<intents>)


@bot.event
async def on_ready()
    global member


@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    emoji = payload.emoji.name
    canal = payload.channel_id
    message = payload.message_id
    roles = bot.get_guild(payload.guild_id).roles
    bro_role = get(roles, name="Bro")
    member = bot.get_guild(payload.guild_id).get_member(payload.user_id)

    if emoji == "bro_emoji" and canal == 920004461575954472 and message == 920004958923939901:
        print('Role acquired')
        await member.add_roles(bro_role) # Issue here
        await member.send("Bro role acquired") # Issue here
```